# Lambda function completes run. Then runs again and crashes

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I have a lambda function that calls a docker image from ECR. I ran the docker image on my local machine and it runs fine but the moment test on Lambda it runs and finishes and then runs again.

Here is the error

```
'updatedRows': 1, 'updatedColumns': 1, 'updatedCells': 1}}
done
END RequestId: c20b4f94-0b27-4edc-bff6-e411d6d163f1
REPORT RequestId: c20b4f94-0b27-4edc-bff6-e411d6d163f1  Duration: 305675.98 ms  Billed Duration: 305676 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 206 MB 
RequestId: c20b4f94-0b27-4edc-bff6-e411d6d163f1 Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError
```

Done indicates the program has been completed. I have set the timeout to 15 mins but it doesnt take that long and I dont get a time out error.

Here is the docker code

```
# Dockerfile, Image, container

FROM python:3.9


COPY . /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt 

CMD ["python", "./run.py"]
```

I have checked and I dont call the function anywhere except in run.py.
All run.py does is call the function.

```
from dev_main import runJobs as run

run()
```

and in dev_main.py I dont call any functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I first have to admit I am really disappointed with the response I got from here and the AWS discord. Toxicity in this community can be horrible.

Anyways. This is a very unique issue and lambda can be really unique in how it works and executes, this article outlines it quite nicely https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

The main issue was my docker file.

In the Dockerfile I had

```
CMD ["python", "./run.py"]
```

which would run just fine with lambda, but then lambda would treat it as some sort of error, but not give any good form of feedback.

The issue is that you need this format

in run.py I needed this function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    run()
```

and in my Dockerfile I needed

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy function code
COPY dev_main.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY run.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.
COPY keys.json .
COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "run.lambda_handler" ]
```